# Is there a way to capture these data points using regular expressions in Python?

Tags: python

Using regular expressions, what is the best way to capture the following values from the text below?

**Data Points To Extract:**

- Question Number (13)
- Question Text (Certification and Accreditation (C&A or CnA) is a process for implementing information security. It is a systematic procedure for evaluating, describing, testing...)
- Possible Answers (Text of A, B, C, D, or another answer ID)
- Correct Answers (A, D...)
- Explanation ("Certification Depends on Only One Thing" - www.actu...)

**Sample Text:**

> QUESTION NO: 13
>
> Certification and Accreditation (C&A or CnA) is a process for
> implementing information security. It is a systematic procedure for
> evaluating, describing, testing, and authorizing systems prior to or
> after a system is in operation. Which of the following statements are
> true about Certification and Accreditation?
>
> Each correct answer represents a complete solution. Choose two.
>
> A. Accreditation is the official management decision given by a senior
> agency official to authorize operation of an information system.
>
> B. Accreditation is a comprehensive assessment of the management,
> operational, and technical security controls in an information system.
>
> C. Certification is the official management decision given by a senior
> agency official to authorize operation of an information system.
>
> D. Certification is a comprehensive assessment of the management,
> operational, and technical security controls in an information system.
>
> Answer: A,D
>
> Explanation:
>
> "Certification Depends on Only One Thing" - [www.actualanswers.com](http://www.actualanswers.com) 8ISC
> CAP Exam
>
> QUESTION NO: 14
>
> Which of the following requires all general support systems and major
> applications to be fully certified and accredited before these systems
> and applications are put into production?
>
> Each correct answer represents a part of the solution. Choose all that
> apply.
>
> A. NIST
>
> B. FIPS
>
> C. FISMA
>
> D. Office of Management and Budget (OMB)
>
> Answer: C,D
>
> Explanation:

**What I've Tried:**

`(?:QUESTION NO: )(\d+)` - This gives me the question number, but nothing more.

`(?:QUESTION NO: )(\d+)(\w+)` - This breaks the previous attempt, but I was trying to capture the question text in the second group.

Comment: I'd suggest two steps: first, capture everything that belongs to one question; then use one or more other regex to get the individual parts from the first match.

Comment: I've been working with RegEx a lot recently I can probably help but a bit confused with the question. What exactly do you want to capture/isolate here?

Comment: Apologies @user3667054 - I tried to include those details in the list under Data Points To Extract, but perhaps it wasn't clear. `(?:QUESTION NO: )(\d+)(.+)(?:A\.)(.+)(?:B\.)(.+)(?:C\.)(.+)(?:D\.)(.+)(?:Answer:)(.+)(?:Explanation:)(.+)` almost gives me what I need, but it doesn't capture these groups for each question; only a single question.